# VBA - If cell value ... then multiple THEN statements

Tags: excel, vba

Objective is to color cell & change font & italicize font of cell in column F based on value in column A.
I have the following code, but when testing this, I keep getting a black cell in F...Strange because if I only have one then statement, it seems to work fine.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lrow
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "TEST" Then
            Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247) And Cells(i, "F").Font.Italic = True And Cells(i, "F").Font.Color = RBG(128, 128, 128)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is a logical connective which combines truth values, not something which sequences statements. If you want two or more statements to be executed in the `if` block -- just put them one after the other without trying to put an `AND` in between. In other words, use

```
If Cells(i, "A").Value = "TEST" Then
        Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
        Cells(i, "F").Font.Italic = True
        Cells(i, "F").Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
End If
```

The code that you had also contained a typo (`RBG` instead of `RGB`) that would prevent it from running at all. Using `Option Explicit` would catch such errors in the compile stage. Fixing that typo, I still found it surprising that your code ran at all. What is happening is an artifact of how VBA uses the same symbol , `=`, for both assignment and equality testing. This causes VBA to parse

```
Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247) And Cells(i, "F").Font.Italic = True And Cells(i, "F").Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
```

as

```
Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = (RGB(221, 235, 247) And (Cells(i, "F").Font.Italic = True) And (Cells(i, "F").Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)))
```

Since `RGB(221, 235, 247)` evaluates to `16247773`, VBA evaluates your statement as

```
Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = (16247773 And False And False)
```

Which is the same as

```
Cells(i, "F").Interior.Color = 0
```

It is this that sets the color to black.

Also -- why not just use [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) for this rather than VBA?